# Problem adding HDSPMixer to the menu in Ubuntu Studio 18.04

Tags: sound, alsa, xfce

To get sound out of my RME Hammerfall HDSP 9652 in Ubuntu Studio 18.04 I need to run the HDSPMixer software first, then I can close it, and the audio will keep on running. The _HDSPMixer came with the Alsa Tools GUI package and was already installed with Ubuntu Studio, however there was no menu item to run it. Other Alsa-tools were there alright, but not this.
So I located `/usr/bin/ubuntustudio/applications/hdspmixer.desktop` and found that it just had one line:

```
[Desktop Entry]
```

I edited it until it looked like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=hdspmixer.desktop
Exec=</usr/bin/hdspmixer>
Icon=hdspmixer
Categories=Audio-Production;Mixers-and-Card-Control
```

And now the hdspmixer appears on the menu, right where it should be. But when I click on the menu entry I get the error:

```
Failed to run the child process "</usr/bin/hdspmixer>" (The file or catalog doesn't exist).
```

Of course they do exist. If I run hdspmixer from the terminal there's no problem.

What to do to get a working menu item?

Comment: You didn't specify any executable file in the `Exec` line (`/usr/bin/` is a directory).

Comment: Good suggestion, I thought so too and tried that, but changing it to /usr/bin/hdspmixer  doesn't change anything.

Comment: I've found out that the file /usr/share/applications/HDSPMixer plays a role. If I change the Name line to HDSPMixer and Exec line to /usr/share/applications/HDSPMixer the application starts properly from the xfce menu. However, all the other entrys on the Audio Production submenu are gone. My, xfce is confusing!

Comment: SOLVED - I've left the Categories blank, which restored the Audio Production submenu to it's former state with the addition of a new Item HDSPMixer which I can run properly. I will not try to touch the xfce menu further!!!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the `Exec` key:

```
Exec=</usr/bin/hdspmixer>
```

This needs to be

```
Exec=/usr/bin/hdspmixer
```

since `</usr/bin/hdspmixer>` is not a valid path, which is why the error says it didn't exist.